# jquery page refreshes regardless of return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have been struggling with this code for a while now I am trying to validate a form using jquery without but the page refreshes regardless of return false.

Here is my code

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function () {
        $('.signup input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == name) {
                $('<p>Please enter your ' + $(".default-value").attr("value") + ' </p>').appendTo('.form_error');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you verified that the code inside of the if statement is executing?

Comment: provide your website URL so i can see errors . Or create jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return false;` in `click` function.

Comment: this is the answer thanx alot I simply put return false in in the click function what a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return false`, try [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event of your `submit` button, as follows:

```
 $('.btn-submit').click(function(e) {
    $('.signup input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == name) { 
            $('<p>Please enter your '+ $(".default-value").attr("value") + ' </p>').appendTo('.form_error');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```